# How can I config dynamically created rectangles on Tkinter Canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

So I'm creating a image-to-word matching game on Tkinter in Python. The user can select how many images/words they'd like to play with/match, and I need a red rectangle to correspond to each image. The code that I used to create these rectangles is as follows:

```
for item in wordList: ##creating the image and its corresponding rectangle
    cv.create_image(xVal*i, 100, image=item[0])
    cv.create_rectangle(xVal*(i-1)+10, 445, xVal*(i+1)-10, 475, fill="red")
    i += 2
```

Where wordList is the list of images that will be shown to the user. 
What I wanted to do is have the rectangle for each image turn green if the user enters the right word into an Entry widget. However, I have no idea how to access/config the rectangles that were made.

Any ideas?

Comment: Change to `iid = cv.create_rectangle(...`. Later on you can do: `cv.itemconfig(iid, fill='green')` Read [Canvas.itemconfig-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.itemconfig-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you create an item on a canvas, the function will return a unique id. You can use that id laster as the first argument to the `itemconfigure` method. You just need to store those ids and use them later.

Alternatively, if each word in `wordList` is unique, you can use the word as a tag, and treat the tag as if it were the unique id. In the following example, both the image and rectangle have the word as a tag. The rectangle also has a tag that is the word with the prefix "rect-".

```
for item in wordList: ##creating the image and its corresponding rectangle
    cv.create_image(xVal*i, 100, image=item[0], tags=(item,))
    cv.create_rectangle(xVal*(i-1)+10, 445, xVal*(i+1)-10, 475, fill="red", 
        tags=(item, "rect-"+item))
    i += 2
```

With that, you could configure the rectangle for the word "hello" with something like this:

```
cv.itemconfigure("rect-hello", fill="green")
```